# Pointer to pointer C++

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, dynamic

I can't really understand what pointer to pointer is in C++. Let's say I have a class defined as follows:

```
class Vector3 
{
   public:
         float x,y,z;
         //some constructors and methods
}
```

Now what if I have something like

```
Vector3 **myVector3;
```

Is this SOMEHOW the C#'s equivalent of saying `List<List<Vector3> myVector3`?
And anyway, how can I dynamically allocate this myVector3 object?
Thanks.

Comment: First, find out what a pointer is (I'll wait). OK, step two: think about what the address of a pointer would be good for.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Let's not confuse the OP further; there need not be an address of a pointer. `null` is a pointer but it has no address; it's a value. **Variables** have an address. A variable may *contain* a pointer.

Comment: @EricLippert Now you're confusing me! I meant that the only reason to have a pointer to a pointer, is to do something with the address of a pointer.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: You would not ask what the address of the number 123 was; numbers are values. Pointers refer to variables; a variable might contain the value 123, but the pointer is not to the value 123, it is to the variable that contains it. Pointers are like numbers. They're values. They don't have an address. The storage location that contains the value has an address.

Comment: @EricLippert I may not be Eric Lippert, but I've been using multiple indirection for 20 years and I understand perfectly well what int ** pp is. If I should have been calling it something other than "a pointer to a pointer" all this time, or using it for something other than storing the address of a pointer to an integer (either of which might be NULL, thank you), I guess I'll just have to answer to Brian Ritchie for that when I get to heaven. If you've mistaken me for an idiot, I regret that, but that's the Internet. Life goes on.

Comment: @EricLippert Whoops, Brian Ritchie plays bass in the Violent Femmes. Dennis Ritchie is the guy I'll have to explain myself to at the Pearly Gates. That's what I get for typing before my first cup of coffee, but at least I dated myself accurately.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: No one is suggesting that you're an idiot. My point is: a pointer *is* an address, and a *variable* that contains a pointer *has* an address. The OP is possibly confused about the relationship between pointers and addresses, and *variables of pointer type have two relationships with addresses*: they both have an address and contain an address. I'm therefore advocating *not* taking the common-but-confusing shortcuts that experts take, like saying "a pointer to a pointer" when they mean "a pointer to a variable containing a pointer".

Comment: @EricLippert I gotcha. My gut sense is that that won't clarify it for the average beginner, but I admit I don't have any data to back that up (and I haven't been in his mental shoes since 1995). But in this particular case, I think OP doesn't even have a *poor* understanding of pointers -- I think he was guessing they might be a container class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this SOMEHOW the C#'s equivalent of saying `List<List<Vector3> myVector3`?

No.

> And anyway, how can I dynamically allocate this `myVector3` object?

I don't understand the question.

> I can't really understand what pointer to pointer is in C++.

Go back to first principals. What is a variable?  A variable is *storage* for a *value* of a particular *type*.

What operations are available on variables?  They may be *read from*, *written to*, or their *address may be taken*.

What is the result of the address-taking operator, `&`?  A pointer to the variable.

What is a pointer?  A *value* that represents a *variable*.

What operations are available on pointer values?  A pointer may be *dereferenced* using `*`. Doing so produces a *variable*.  (There are other operations available on pointers but let's not worry about those.)

So let's sum up.

`Foo foo;` is a variable of type `Foo`. It can contain a `Foo`.

`&foo` is a pointer. It is a value. When dereferenced it produces the variable `foo`:

```
Foo foo;
Foo *pfoo = &foo;
*pfoo = whatever; // same as foo = whatever
```

`pfoo` is a variable. A variable may have its address taken:

```
Foo **ppfoo = &pfoo;
*ppfoo = null;  // Same as pfoo = null.  Not the same as foo = null.
```

So there you go. `ppfoo` is a variable. It contains a value. Its value is a pointer. When that pointer is dereferenced it produces a variable. That variable contains a value. That value is a pointer. When it is dereferenced it produces a variable. That variable is of type `Foo`.

Make sure this is very clear in your mind.  When you get confused, **go back to first principles**.  Pointers are values, they may be dereferenced, doing so produces a variable. Everything flows from that.

Comment: Ok, first of all I want to thank you for this great explanation. I am 100% that i do understand your explanation. I do understand what pointers are, what referencing and dereferencing pointers means. But I still have something that I don't understand and I think the best think I could do is to describe the actual code that is messing me up.

Comment: I have that class Vector3.
     I have another class called Polygon, and inside this I have a public method called `AddVertex(int numberOfVertices)`, which adds a number of  Vector3 objects to form the actual Polygon.
    So the way that I would do this is:
 `Vector3 *myVerticesList = new Vector3[numberOfVertices]` , and then Initialize this array of Vector3 objects.
    But the actual code is a little different:
 `Vector3 ** myVerticesList = new Vector3*[numberOfVertices]`. I don't understand why is using a pointer to pointer list instead of just using a pointer list.

Comment: Sorry, but I really want to figure it out and I'm not very familiarized with C++.

Comment: @RaducuMihai: The `myVerticesList` is a pointer. It points to a variable. What variable? An array is a collection of variables. The pointed-to variable is the first element in an array. Each variable in the array has a value. What is the value?  A pointer to a variable. What does that variable contain? A vector.

Comment: @RaducuMihai: Now I understand why you were asking about lists. This is most like a list of vectors, but you're right, it could actually be more like a list of lists of vectors. If your question is "why is this code written using a confusing mixture of arrays, pointers and standard library container types?" I do not know. I would be inclined to simply make a standard list of standard vectors. The person you should ask is the person who wrote this code.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ equivalent of a List would be std::vector. Never mind that your class is called vector; this is a vector as in a dynamically expandable sequence of like-typed objects.

If you want a list of lists of Vector3 in C++, you want

```
std::vector<std::vector<Vector3> myVectorVectorVictor;
```

And that allocates one too. No pointers needed.

Comment: I don't want to use a List<List<Vector3>> in C++. I just want to understand what pointer to pointer means

Comment: @RaducuMihai In that case, I'll revert to my comment above: First find out what a pointer is. It's an address in memory -- implicitly, the address OF something. Maybe it's the address of another pointer -- or maybe you just have a variable int **p which is declared as the address of a pointer to an int. It may be null, and not actually point to a valid pointer to an int. You need to read up about pointers, nobody's going to explain it here in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector3 **myVector3;
```

Is basically just a pointer pointing to another pointer. Dereferencing it gives you a pointer to a `Vector3`.

example :

```
#include <iostream>

class Vector3
{
public:
    float x, y, z;
    //some constructors and methods
};

int main()
{
    Vector3 **myVector3 = new Vector3*[50]; // allocate 50 Vector3 pointers and set myVector3 to the first, these are only pointers, pointing to nothing.
    //myVector3[0]->x; myVector3[0] is a Vector3 pointer, currently pointing to nothing dereferencing this will result in Undefined Behaviour
    myVector3[0] = new Vector3; // allocate a Vector3 on the heap and let pointer 1 ( of the 50 ) point to this newly allocated object.
    myVector3[0]->x = 5;
    std::cout << "myVector3[0]->x : " << myVector3[0]->x; // prints "myVector3[0]->x : 5"
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Ok, so why would I use Vector3 **myVector3 = new Vector3[50] instead of using Vector3 *myVector3 = new Vector3[50];

Comment: @RaducuMihai You missed the `*` in `new Vector3*[50]` which allocates an array of pointers, not an array of `Vector3`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
Vector3 * pointer = new Vector3; // points to a instance of Vector3 on the heap
Vector3 * * pointerToPointer = & pointer; // points to pointer; we take the address of pointer
```

Comment: I will reformulte: What is the use of pointers to pointers? :D

Comment: As other answers have hinted, one of the uses is when constructing multi-dimensional C arrays.